# Having issues triggering the proximity sensor in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sensors, proximitysensor

I am trying to use the proximity sensor in my phone using unity remote.
I tried to follow this [Documentation](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.ProximitySensor.html)

The input system is working fine. I have everything installed and I've imported all the samples,also unity remote is working and I've tested the sensor on my android device using Sensor Test App.

/*All I want to do is trigger this script and test if it's working or not. I could not attach it to a gameObject because it is not derived from MonoBehaviour.*/

EDIT : I've changed the script to MonoBehaviour.before, It was derived from Sensor

This is my new sensor script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Controls;

public class Prox : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ProximitySensor proximity;

private void Start()
{

    if (ProximitySensor.current != null)
    {
        var _ProximitySensor = ProximitySensor.current;
        InputSystem.EnableDevice(_ProximitySensor);
        Debug.Log("proximity sensor is working");
    }
    Debug.Log("proximity error");
}
void Update()
{

    if (proximity != null)
    {
      //  InputSystem.EnableDevice(proximity);
        var _ProximitySensor = ProximitySensor.current;
        Debug.Log(_ProximitySensor);
        var _dist = _ProximitySensor.distance;
        Debug.Log(_dist);
    }
    else
    {
       Debug.Log("null");
    }
}
}
```

The output from the console is always returning "proximity error"
this means I'm getting null value from ProximitySensor.current.
What I want to do is move a gameObject when the proximity sensor is triggered (the user is holding the phone to their ear).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! You code is clearly `c#` ...

Comment: thank you for the clarification I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting "proximity error" because the code that displays it is in the Start() function and it will always be executed. You have to write:

```
private void Start()
{
    if (ProximitySensor.current != null)
    {
        var _ProximitySensor = ProximitySensor.current;
        InputSystem.EnableDevice(_ProximitySensor);
        Debug.Log("proximity sensor is working");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("proximity error");
    }
}
```

Comment: this function is returning proximity error the sensor is not working.
 I don't know why this is happening, I've tested the sensor in my android device with sensor test App